# Is there a performance impact to block level vs function level scoping in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, performance, scope

I was reviewing some C# code and came across some variables that were scoped at the function level that I would have scoped inside the code block (a loop in this case) where they are used.  To me scoping as close to the is just cleaner and easier to reason about and that is reason enough to prefer block level scope.  But I was wondering, is there any significant performance impact one way or another?

Comment: Twould depend on the size of the loop and variable -- in most cases probably no differance

Comment: related http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/113262/why-declare-variables-close-to-where-they-are-used

Comment: @AlexKrups Would it? I imagine the compiler would hoist the declaration out of the loop either way.

Comment: It makes no difference whatsoever.  .NET compilers generate MSIL, it doesn't have the notion of block scope.  Some details on how the jitter tracks local variable use in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034).  Focus only on writing readable code.

Comment: Cannot comment with out see code. Please supply code in question.

Comment: @Rotem I guess i didn't fully think this through - I assume that the GC is smart enough to dispose of the last iteration of the item at the conclusion of the loop as opposed to the conclusion of the function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no performance difference at all.

The variable scope is different from the variable lifetime. The variable is created in stack frame for the function, regardless if it is declared in the function scope or in a code block in the function. The variable exists during the entire function execution, it's only the compiler that limits the access to the variable depending on its scope.

(Note though that different rules apply if the variable is actually a part of a closure instead of a regular local variable.)

Comment: And of course the JITter is free to reuse a register or part of the stack for multiple variables with non overlapping live times.

Comment: That is along the lines that I figured, though I had thought that perhaps the difference in scoping might effect garbage collection.

Comment: @MatthewNichols: Actually it doesn't affect garbage collection either (except in debug mode). The garbage collector only cares about where in the code the reference is used, the scope and the lifetime of the variable is irrelevant.

Comment: @Guffa yes that is what I figured out from your answer. I should brush up on my garbage collection lore.